# oidc-client-js and basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, basic-authentication, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

## Scenario

- ASP.NET Core MVC (API) with IdentityServerAuthentication, Angular 2 with [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). IdentityServer4, with ASP.NET Core Identity, as OP. Using Kestrel
- nginx reverse proxy - SSL termination, Basic Authentication
- oidc Implicit Flow

Authentication flow is as follows:

1. Browser navigates to app
2. Basic authentication in browser
3. Angular route guard notices (via oidc-client) that user is not signed in (or 401 is caught)
4. App navigates to `unauthorized` route
5. User clicks on `sign in` button, triggering UserManager (oidc-client) `signinRedirect`
6. Browser is redirected to OP (IdentityServer4)
7. User logs in at OP
8. Redirect to app signin-callback - i.e. UserManager `signinRedirectCallback`
9. Basic Authentication popup - because oidc-client calls `connect/userinfo` with Bearer authorization header.

## Issue

The user is now stuck on step 9. The call is never made with the basic authentication header (or rather: both headers combined). The user can only cancel, which then yields a 401 on the request to the userinfo endpoint, leaving them signed out in the app.

Repeated tries would skip step 5 because the session cookie for the sign-in at the OP still exists.

I'm not entirely sure how the browser handles basic authentication, especially on requests made from js/angular. Could this be a bug in `oidc-client-js`?

I would guess that our app's authenticated HTTP requests would have to check if there already is an Authorization and add the bearer token to it (comma separated authorization headers, but only one such header). We already append an Authorization header with the bearer token if no Authorization header is yet send - but I cannot really experiment with that since this scenario does not even proceed far enough to make such api calls.

#### Everything works when Basic Authentication is not set

I'm using a local nginx during development to test HTTPS redirect, detection of SSL termination - and also the behaviour when Basic Authentication is added.

Everything works fine without Basic Authentication. `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers are interpreted correctly, HTTP is redirected to HTTPS etc.

## Why do you even need Basic Authentication?

We do not want to have the application publicly available. OIDC based authentication has been added recently, as well as enforcing HTTPS etc. (app is not yet in production)